# Make return call from nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function runimage(){
  var vel = val.id;
  var secondlink = 'someurl'+vel+'stuff';                       

  $.getJSON(secondlink, function(beyta){
      var target = beyta.attachments.data[0].media.image.src;
      return target;
  });

  return "FISH";
}
```

I am making an API call via jQuery's `getJSON` method. The problem I am having is getting the `runimage()` function return the value of my `target` value.

The code `return target` gives me `undefined`. This is the result even if I place a dummy string in place of `target`.

To see if this is a problem with closures, I added a dummy `return "FISH"` outside of my getJSON call, and the code does indeed return `"FISH"`

How would I go about getting `runimage()` to return the value of variable `target`?

Comment: You can't! `$.getJson` is asynchronous.

Comment: Consider callback continuations or promises to handle async operations

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that while you are waiting to get your AJAX response, the function has already returned "FISH".

Comment: I should clarify that the dummy is used as a test. Not at the same time as my original code. I only added it in here to see if it was an issue with closures.

Comment: @ibrahim mahrir Please don't add new content to other people's answers. Add a comment instead. Thank you.

Comment: You should look into JavaScript "promises" to resolve this.